# Migrate multilingual Drupal 7 users to Drupal 8

Tags: 8, migrations

I have Drupal 7 users that uses Profile module and has fields for individual languages i.e. presentation_sv, presentation_en that I would like to migrate to a proper Entity translated Drupal 8.

First migration file:

```
id: custom_user
label: "Custom User accounts"
migration_group: custom
migration_tags:
  - Custom D7
class: Drupal\user\Plugin\migrate\User
source:
  plugin: d7_user
process:
  langcode:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: sv
  name: name
  pass: pass
  mail: mail
  created: created
  access: access
  login: login
  status: status
  presentation: profile_presentation_sv
destination:
  plugin: entity:user
```

Here is the translations migration file:

```
id: custom_user_translations
label: "Translated Custom User accounts"
migration_group: custom
migration_tags:
  - Custom D7
class: Drupal\user\Plugin\migrate\User
source:
  plugin: d7_user
  translations: true
process:
  uid:
    plugin: migration
    source: uid
    migration: custom_user
  langcode:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: en
  name: name
  pass: pass
  mail: mail
  created: created
  access: access
  login: login
  status: status
  presentation: profile_presentation_en
destination:
  plugin: entity:user
  translations: true
migration_dependencies:
  required:
    - custom_user
```

The error I get:

```
Next Drupal\Core\Database\DatabaseExceptionWrapper: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'map.destid2' in 'field list': SELECT map.sourceid1 AS sourceid1, map.destid1 AS destid1, map.destid2 AS destid2
FROM
{migrate_map_custom_user_translations} map
ORDER BY destid1 ASC; Array
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your migration configuration needs to be re-installed. When I had that issue I deleted the map table (in your case `migrate_map_custom_user_translations`) and then re-installed the config (I used the `config_devel` module).